# Button that shows a modal that include page inside of it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can i type a JQuery or Ajax script that When i click on (for example) `<button>WORLDS</button>` shows a modal in the same page that `include` a page out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didn't provided any code, I will answer your question, hoping it will help you. You can use an `iframe` for the external page part:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.overlay, .popup').fadeIn();
});
$('.overlay').on('click', function() {
  $('.overlay, .popup').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.popup {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>WORLDS</button>
<div class='overlay'>
  <div class='popup'>
    <iframe width='' src="http://stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, You totally answered my question, But unfortunately i typed it wrong, Sorry about that, But the real question would be like that (I have page1 has a button, I want when i click this button to show page2 inside page1, With the idea that page2 contain a modal) in more clear way (page1 shows page2 content which is modal)

Comment: I'm glad it worked. The same idea applies @J.4RK, only that you create a modal in the second page too. Unfortunately I can't create two different pages on stackoverflow to demonstrate it, but it should work based on the code from my answer.